# Cannot connect to SQL Server using VMWare

Tags: sql-server, windows, vmware

I am having problem connecting to a SQL Server database on windows 7 from SQL Server Management Studio on vmware.

Is there any setting that I must set to be on or off in my windows 7?

Comment: are Sql server and management studio in the same vmware computer? or you want to connect to sql server from your local machine

Comment: What does "having problem" mean? Do you have errors? What version and edition of SQL Server?

Comment: Which protocol are you using - TCP? Is that set up correctly on your PC? Can you connect to it from another physical PC on your network? What network setting do you have for your VMware machine - bridged, private?

Comment: my sql server is sql server 2005 developer edition sp3 installed on host machine (windows 7) and the sql server management studio from wich i'm try to connect is installed on vmware.

Comment: the host and the vmware is using HOST ONLY setting and well connected and i can see the instance of sql server on my host.